# Apache Beam stream processing of json data

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am analyzing Apache Beam stream processing of data. I have worked on Apache Kafka stream processing (Producer, Consumer etc). I want to compare it with Beam now.

I want to to stream simple json data using Apache Beam programmatically (Java).

```
{"UserID":"1","Address":"XXX","ClassNo":"989","UserName":"Stella","ClassType":"YYY"}
```

Can someone please guide me or direct me with an example link?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple aspects of this:

- first you need to establish where the data is coming from:

  - you need to use some kind of IO in Beam pipeline, see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pipeline-io);
  - there are a bunch of built in IOs, see the list [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/);
  - by using an IO from the above link you will likely get a stream of strings containing those JSON objects;
  - some IOs can natively parse Avro and other formats (PubsubIO), this depends on specific IO implementation;
- then you may need to transform the data:

  - you will need to create your own PTransform which handles the conversion from a JSON string to your Java class:

    - see the section about PTransforms [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#applying-transforms);
  - you can see an example of such transform [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a350152c298fc82b58ccdac91539ba9cc6931038/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/JsonToRow.java#L64):

    - this JsonToRow PTransform accepts a string with JSON object and converts it to a Beam [Row](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/Row.java#L56) using Jackson ObjectMapper;
    - you can either try using the Row object yourself, or you can implement a similar transform to convert JSON strings to your custom Java type instead of Row;
- you may also take a look at [examples folder](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/examples/java) in Beam source;

Comment: Excellent! What I understood is, (1.) I can read a json file using IO (Lets say TextIO). (2.) Then use PTransform to convert JSON to Beam Row.

Comment: I have some questions. Beam Row is the Streaming object here? How do we stream the data using stream API here? or Any suggestion on which file helps me to start with in the example folder? After streaming of data, where will the data be stored? Because, in this case Kafka has clusters.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the Streaming object or stream API. I think the best place to start is from the top of the programming guide: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/ . It describes basic Beam model before going into the details. And here's the example on how to run Beam basic examples: https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/

Comment: In few words: in Beam you define a data pipeline which consists of transforms that you want to apply to your data. Data comes in and goes out to/from IOs, which are a special case of data transformations. You define which IO to get data from and how, and which IO and how it should go to. Pipeline is then executed on a Runner, for example you can run Beam pipelines on Google Cloud Dataflow, Apache Spark, or Apache Flink. How you manage your cluster will depend on the runner you choose

Comment: Row is just an example of the data types supported by the Beam Java SDK out of the box. You can use your own data types. Overall pipeline flow you described is correct. You read data from IO, implement a PTransform to convert the data to the format you're comfortable working with, then apply more transforms if needed. Then you send the data out to another IO.

Comment: Beam is really confusing. I am not getting exactly how this model works. Is there any architecture diagram or model diagram how does it work? Looks like, Beam is only a SDK. I mean Streaming API is nothing like Apache Kafka has a Streaming functions which will stream the data for reference: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/

Comment: I can see how it can be confusing. There are couple of presentations about Beam, for example this one: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1SHie3nwe-pqmjGum_QDznPr-B_zXCjJ2VBDGdafZme8/edit#slide=id.g12846a6162_0_5

And few others can be found here https://beam.apache.org/community/presentation-materials/

Comment: The goal of Beam is to define a programming model for distributed data processing, abstracting away specifics of supported execution environment. By model I mean key concepts of data processing and the rules of how they work together. For example pipelines, ptransforms, windows, triggers, are few key parts of the model. One of the purposes is to be able to define a data pipeline in a portable way, so that you can run it in any supported execution environment and language depending on your needs.

Comment: With Beam you should theoretically be able to create a Beam pipeline in Golang, Python, or Java using the same concepts, and run it for example on a local or cloud Flink cluster if it works for you, or run it in Cloud Dataflow in a fully managed, autoscaling environment. With Kafka  API you are writing code against Kafka and it will only work on a Kafka cluster unless their SDK is specifically supported in other environments.

Comment: Whether you choose Kafka, Beam, or other SDK and an execution environment depends on your requirements. I would definitely consider things like familiarity and supportability when choosing it, in addition to performance, portability, specific feature set, etc.